# Smooth Mouse Action Implementation in React using GSAP

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, gsap

I'm trying to implement smooth scrolling action using GSAP in react. **Note that this is different from usual smooth scrolling**. An example of what I'm trying to replicate can be seen in [this](https://plasticbcn.com) website:

This is my attempt:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TweenLite } from 'gsap';

const Scroller = () => {
  const [scroller, setScroller] = useState({
    target: null,
    ease: 0.05,
    endY: 0,
    y: 0,
    resizeRequest: 1,
    scrollRequest: 0,
  });

  const requestRef = useRef(null);

  const onLoad = () => {
    updateScroller();
    window.focus();
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  };

  const updateScroller = () => {
    const resized = scroller.resizeRequest > 0;

    if (resized) {
      const height = scroller.target.clientHeight;
      document.body.style.height = height + "px";
      setScroller(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        resizeRequest: 0,
      }));
    }

    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;

    setScroller(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      endY: scrollY,
      y: prevState.y + (scrollY - prevState.y) * prevState.ease,
    }));

    if (Math.abs(scrollY - scroller.y) < 0.05 || resized) {
      setScroller(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        y: scrollY,
        scrollRequest: 0,
      }));
    }

    TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
      y: -scroller.y,
    });

    requestRef.current = scroller.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller) : null;
  };

  const onScroll = () => {
    setScroller(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      scrollRequest: prevState.scrollRequest + 1,
    }));

    if (!requestRef.current) {
      requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  };

  const onResize = () => {
    setScroller(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      resizeRequest: prevState.resizeRequest + 1,
    }));

    if (!requestRef.current) {
      requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(updateScroller);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setScroller(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      target: document.querySelector("#scroll-container"),
    }));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scroller.target) {
      TweenLite.set(scroller.target, {
        rotation: 0.01,
        force3D: true,
      });
    }
  }, [scroller.target]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
      window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section className="viewport">
      <div id="scroll-container" className="scroll-container">
        <div className="content">

          <div className="img-container">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/splash-10.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="img-container">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/splash-14.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="img-container">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/splash-15.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="img-container">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/106114/splash-16.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Scroller;
```

However, this is not working. There is no error whatsoever, but there is no difference in the scrolling action either.

Please help me out, thanks in advance!